# Oracle partition using 2 columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table as like below

```
Id RC_CLASS  RC_DATE    RC_TYPE
14 FI-321619 22-Jan-16   S
14 FI-399481 29-Jan-16   D
14 FI-321619 20-Jan-17   S
```

Here is what i tried

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT rc.*,
             RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ID,RC_CLASS order by rc__date) AS LATEST_VERSION
      FROM table
     )
WHERE LATEST_VERSION = 1 
ORDER BY rc_vendorid;
```

Expected output

```
Id RC_CLASS  RC_DATE    RC_TYPE
14 FI-399481 29-Jan-16   D
14 FI-321619 20-Jan-17   S
```

I wanna group by ID and Class and bring top one sort by the RC_DATE. What i am getting is always the top one based on date, partition is not working here. What is missing?

Comment: What is the issue with your query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are very close.  Basically, you just need a *descending* sort to get the latest version:

```
SELECT rc.*
FROM (SELECT rc.*,
             RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, RC_CLASS ORDER BY rc_date DESC) AS LATEST_VERSION
      FROM table rc
     ) rc
WHERE LATEST_VERSION = 1
ORDER BY rc_vendorid;
```

I note that you use `RANK()` for this.  This can return duplicates, if you have two rows on the same date.  If that is not desirable, you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` which would arbitrarily choose one (if all the other keys are the same).

Comment: Thanks it worked. Also as you said i used ROW_NUMBER() it gave me exactly what i need. Rank gave me 396 records and ROW_NUMBER gave me 394, 2 duplicates. Perfect